# Непонятные символы вместо русских букв при попытке получения сайта через request.get Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, кодировка, beautiful-soup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://health-diet.ru/table_calorie"
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "user-agent": "  "
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

src = req.text
with open("index.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(src)
```

После сохранения сайта в файл, вместо русских букв появляются такие символы:

```html
<a class="mzr-tc-group-item-href" href="/base_of_food/food_24515/" title="���������� ������ ��������: ���� � �����">���� � �����</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: у меня нормально возвращает, возможно на компе нет кириллицы?

Comment: Надо кодировку явно указывать `with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file: file.write(src)` или писать в файл сразу байтами: `with open("index.html", "wb") as file: file.write(req.content)`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало